# Accessing inherited objects in lazy initializing swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, lazy-initialization

Just wondering why I can't access the inherited object collectionView when lazy initializing:

```
class FunCollectionLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var middleSection:Int = {
        let sectionCount = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections()
        return sectionCount/2
    }()

    func testFunc() {
        print((self.collectionView?.numberOfSections())! / 2)
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> FunCollectionLayout' has no member 'collectionView'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing the `lazy` declaration attribute.

```
  lazy var middleSection:Int = {
    let sectionCount = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections()
    return sectionCount/2
  }()
```

But you are missing the point by not making this a computed property.

```
  var middleSection: Int {
    let sectionCount = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections()
    return sectionCount / 2
  }
```

Keep it dynamic, keep it in sync with the `collectionView`, make it a computed property.